# Notepad++ not launching HTML files in web browser

Tags: html5, notepadqq

I have installed Notepad++ first time in Ubuntu, I am trying to launch an HTML file in browser, but it shows shell error

[image]

Comment: Did you install it via Wine or Snap?

Comment: I installed it from Ubuntu Software Centre

Comment: notepadqq does not have run with browser function like notepad++ has

Comment: Unlike Notepad++ which does not have a working run with browser functionality in Ubuntu, only a useless error message window, Geany and Brackets have working run with browser functionality.